# Function to print list to specific buffers

Tags: buffers, print

I am using the following function to print a list to a specific buffer.  For instance, I can use `(print-list greek "*Messages*")` to print in the `*Messages*` buffer.  So I can print to a buffer that already exists.  But if I do not pass optional `bufr`, I want to use the `*Messages*` buffer.

```
(defun print-list (list &optional bufr)
  "DESC"

  (with-current-buffer bufr

    (dolist (elm list)
      (princ elm)
      (princ "\n"))

    (princ (mapconcat #'identity list "\n"))))
```

Comment: What part of the manual did you check when you were looking for a solution on your own, before you asked here?

Comment: I can print in a buffer and in a temp buffer.  But not how to make a function recognise what type of buffer to use.  Perhaps a `cond` clause I would think.

Comment: Could use `(with-current-buffer`.  Have not got anything that works yet, except if I specify the buffer directly, not through a function.

Comment: That doesn’t answer my question.

Comment: "2.1 Buffer Names" but is not very practical

Comment: I know that `with-current-buffer` could work, but then cannot get to pass the `*Messages*` buffer correctly.

Comment: The funny thing is that with `(with-current-buffer "*Messages*"` does work.  But then passing the buffer through the function gets me stuck.

Comment: Have now fixed the use of the `*Messages*` buffer.

Comment: For future reference, you shouldn’t continually amend your question as you work through a problem. Work through the problem first, and only when you are really stuck should you ask a question. Be sure to mention the resources you have used, such as manuals or other questions on this site, to try to work through the problem as well.

Comment: Arg BUFR is optional. If you don't provide it, it's nil. If it's nil then `with-current-buffer` will raise an error.

Comment: Please clean up your question, instead of showing it evolving.

Answer (score 0):

Not every function that operates on buffers will accept a buffer name instead of a buffer object. In particular, you need to consult the help for the `princ` function. (You can use `C-h f` to open a help buffer with documentation about any function.)

```
princ is a function defined in print.c.

Signature
(princ OBJECT &optional PRINTCHARFUN)

Documentation
Output the printed representation of OBJECT, any Lisp object.

…

Optional argument PRINTCHARFUN is the output stream, which can be one
of these:

   - a buffer, in which case output is inserted into that buffer at point;
   - a marker, in which case output is inserted at marker's position;
   - a function, in which case that function is called once for each
     character of OBJECT's printed representation;
   - a symbol, in which case that symbol's function definition is called; or
   - t, in which case the output is displayed in the echo area.

If PRINTCHARFUN is omitted, the value of standard-output (which see)
is used instead.
```

I have omitted some irrelevant information, but if you look carefully you will see that while it accepts many different types of objects for the second argument, it does not accept strings.

Check [chapter 28.3 Buffer Names](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Buffer-Names.html) of the Elisp Manual where you will find out about `get-buffer`, which takes a name and gives back the buffer object with that name. The Elisp tutorial is a good start; in chapters 2.1 and 2.2 mentions `buffer-name` but somehow omits any mention of `get-buffer`.

Comment: The Elisp Tutorial needs more work.

Comment: So you suggest that I do not pass the buffer this way, but call `get-buffer` first?

Comment: On the other hand using `(with-current-buffer bufr` absolves me from using `get-buffer`.

Comment: The problem with `(let ( (bufr (get-buffer name)) )` is that I get `Buffer is read-only: *Messages*`.